# Should I use Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm about to start on a new project but I'm doubting if I should use Multisite for the company's structure or not.

The situation is as follows;

Corporation is based in a few EU countries, which each of the country websites have a consumer website and a professional website.

My thought was; Use multisite to make the consumer/professional switch and use WPML for each website. Things went fine so far. Yet; all websites have one shared product database. I'd like to make a custom post type "Products" and have them available in every language on every website (Consumer/Pro). Yet I cant find a way to have it (easily managable) share that product  database and its relations.

So there's my doubt on using MultiSite, and as of yet, I dont see any other option to get what I want; Consumer/Professional sites, all with their own content, but with a shared product database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `switch_to_blog()` function within your product archive (http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog). This would allow you to get the products from another site within the multisite. Then use `restore_current_blog()` to return back to your individual site.

Comment: Although it was a solution, my problem isnt fixed. The content with switch_to_blog stays in the same site and the permalinks link to the other site. I should stay within that blog. So this isnt an option. I looked at pods but isnt giving a solution either; no shared content between blogs. So I dont think Multisite is the right way for me.